Is a 50 min layover enough for plane changes in Singapore Airport?
I shall be planning to travel to Bali via Singapore.
Will this 50 min layover enough to change planes?


The airline must believe it’s enough or it wouldn’t sell the ticket. You’ll need to clear security AFAIK though, so it looks tight. I wouldn't book it but I’m risk averse when flying. This question is similar to: Is one hour connection time enough to transit at Singapore Changi (SIN) on Scoot airlines?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you @Traveller, this answers my query!

Bali is one of the frequent destinations from Singapore. You will find a ton of flights and Singapore Airlines will rebook into next flight for free. Personally, I have no problem booking this as Singapore Airport is well organized and connections are very fast. Even if you are stuck for a few hours, Singapore Airport is the best place to get stuck.

Should be, but if the BOM-SIN flight is delayed and you miss the connection, go to the transfer desk with both boarding passes and they'll re-route you for free, possibly also covering you for a hotel night if necessary

It's also worth mentioning that Singapore Airlines has six (6) daily flights to Bali, so even if you miss one, you're unlikely to have a long wait for the next.

Thank you @crazydre!!

And, Singapore airport is one of the best airport to be stuck at.
